# ImageIcon By using String Names

Tags: java, swing, awt, event-dispatch-thread

Hi I'm having problems while reading images name into ImageIcon..The Images are not getting loaded into JLabel.The program compiles but the images are not visible in JLabel . Please Help me in finding out the problem here .Thank you in advance

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

class ImageShuffler extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JButton btnStart,btnPausePlay,btnStop;
    JLabel lblImage;
    String [] imageNames ={"1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg","4.jpg","5.jpg","6.jpg","7.jpg","8.jpg","9.jpg","10.jpg","11.jpg"};
    ImageIcon [] images = new ImageIcon [imageNames.length];

    ImageShuffler()
    {
        btnStart= new JButton("Start");
        btnPausePlay=new JButton("Pause/Play");
        btnStop=new JButton("Stop");
        lblImage=new JLabel();

        for(int i=0;i<imageNames.length;i++)
        {
            images[i]=new ImageIcon(imageNames[i]);
        }
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(200,290);
        add(btnStart);
        add(btnPausePlay);
        add(btnStop);
        add(lblImage);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        btnStart.addActionListener(this);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource()==btnStart)
        {
            while(true)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<imageNames.length;j++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        lblImage.setIcon(images[j]);
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        new ImageShuffler();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well where are the files, compared with your working directory?

Comment: `while(true)` within `actionPerformed` - should never enter an loop like this on the EDT

Comment: The Files are in the same folder

Comment: Are any exceptions thrown?

Comment: No Exceptions Thrown .

Comment: As copeg said, that while loop should not be there.

Comment: But i need to run it again and again ...continuos loop

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do, your going about it the wrong way.

Comment: `But i need to run it again and again` why?

Comment: Even if i remove while(true ) loop it doesnt executes 
If i comment thread then only the last image is on the label

Comment: Did you remove the `while` loop *and* the `Thread.sleep` call?

Comment: As i said in my answer, All updates are painted only _after_ the method completes, therefore resulting in the last image only. If you don't remove the `Thread.sleep` it will freeze for `3000 * imageNames.length` millis, then paint last only.

Comment: its doesnot update all the setIcon only the last one is visible on the label

Answer (score 1):

You lock yourself in an infinite loop inside the EDT (`actionPerformed()`), so the graphics is never updated.

Any change made, updates *after* the event proccessing (FYI at `RepaintManager` class, which runs in the EDT - as expected).

In any case where you want continuous changes, use a swing [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html).